# ReactRouter v4 - Redirect doesn't work with Switch

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router

I have a code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Navigation from './Navigation';
import PublicPage from './PublicPage';
import LoginPage from './LoginPage';
import SecuredPage from './SecuredPage';
import {Route, Switch, Redirect, BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Navigation>
            <Switch>
                <Redirect from='/' to='/public'/>
                <Route path="/public" component={PublicPage}/>
                <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage}/>
                <Route path="/secured" component={SecuredPage}/>
            </Switch>
        </Navigation>
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById("react-app")
);
```

Now I want path `/` to redirect to `/public` path but somehow this configuration doesn't work. Other routes stop rendering as well. I think I do everything like in [documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Swap

```
<Redirect from='/' to='/public'/>
```

with

```
<Redirect exact from='/' to='/public'/>
```

because otherwise '/' will match everything, creating an infinite redirect loop

Comment: Thaks boss, this should really be in the documentation! Right now there example just uses a `from='/'`

Comment: Sure, but what if you want to redirect "everything else" to `/public`, like the `default` case of a `switch` statement?

Comment: If you want to remove the `exact` part and have it act like a `default` case of a `switch`, just place the `Redirect` as the last child of the `Switch`. Also, be careful that you only use `Route` and `Redirect` components as children of the `Switch` (see [here](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/10551) for reference).

Answer (score 4):

Complementary to rafty answer there is another solution:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Navigation>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/">
                    <Redirect from='/' to='/public'/>
                </Route>
                <Route path="/public" component={PublicPage}/>
                <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage}/>
                <Route path="/secured" component={SecuredPage}/>
            </Switch>
        </Navigation>
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById("react-app")
);
```

but of course its not as clean.