# Default root in react-router v4 in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I used to use early version of react router the default root can be set using IndexRoute but now in react-router v4 I'm lost.

```
<Switch>
  <Redirect exact from='/' to='/dashboard' />
  <Route exact path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
</Switch>
```

Tried above code doesn't seem to work, no effect on using Redirect.

Comment: Please add more code as your example seems correct. Also, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42875977/reactrouter-v4-redirect-doesnt-work-with-switch) if it helps.

Comment: redirect doesn't have 'exact' prop, but in principle it should work, probably the problem is not in the route declaration https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Route with a path param will always match. You need to configure your Routes properly

```
<Switch>
  {/* Your other Routes */}
  <Route component={Dashboard} />
</Switch>
```

With the help of switch, the first matched Route is rendered and hence you need to order your Routes properly so that a proper Route is rendered

Answer (score 0):

You need to use withRouter
like this:
`export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App))`

Comment: Your answer is poorly worded. The answer should provide a clear explanation. Should not use words like 'maybe'. Please read the SO guidelines before posting.